# creating DELETE request using nodejs on sql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

New to `node.js` and learning how to use `mysql` with `node`. I have a `form.html` that has two buttons to input a `department_no` and a `department_name`. I am succecfully able to insert into `mysql` database but I have no clue on how to delete a specific `dept_no`. What I want to be able to do is enter a `dept_no` and the `dept_name` and then `DELETE` from my database based on the `dept_no`. Also I want to be able to check what the user enters to make sure that it is a valid `dept_no` and `dept_name`. Any ideas on how to get started or what to look into to be able to do this would be extremely helpful. I will paste my `node.js` and `form.html` down below.

`node.js`

```
// DELETE BELOW
app.delete("/deleteEmp/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Department number is " + req.body.department_no);
  console.log("Department name is " + req.body.department_name);

  const deptNumber = req.body.department_no;
  const deptName = req.body.department_name;

  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "employees"
  });

  const queryString = "DELETE departments WHERE dept_no = ?";
  connection.query(queryString, [department_no], (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Could not delete" + err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Deleted department_no with dept_name");
    res.end();
  });
});
```

`form.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>SQLFORM</title>
    <style>
      #space {
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Fill Form Below</div>
    <hr />
    <div id="space">
      <form action="/deleteEmp" method="DELETE">
        <input placeholder="Enter Department Number" name="department_no" />
        <input placeholder="Enter Department Name" name="department_name" />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `const queryString = "DELETE FROM departments WHERE dept_no = ?";` instead.

Comment: but how can I use a `form` and get the info passed into the `form` and delete based on that in my `database`

Comment: this post doesn't explain how to delete from a mysql database using express though @Barns

Comment: You can use sequelizejs (ORM) http://docs.sequelizejs.com/ for performing node database operations. It will make easy for you to perform CRUD operations.

Answer (score 1):

HTML forms do not support `DELETE` requests in general. Node apps can use a work-around like this one - https://github.com/expressjs/method-override

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to perform an AJAX request that doesn't have restrictions on allowed methods. A simplified example:

```
document.querySelector('#space form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('department_no', document.querySelector("input[name='department_no']").value);
  formData.append('department_name', document.querySelector("input[name='department_name']").value);

  fetch('https://yoururl.com/deleteEmp', {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/x-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: formData
  });
});
```